# Automation of Colab Enterprise notebook within BigQuery Studio workspace

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-colab-enterprise

I have a colab notebook stored in BigQuery studio (screen attached, Notebook 1). Essentially, Notebook 1 will take data from a table stored in the same GCP project, perform some transformation and export into another table in the same project. I want to automate this in a way that Notebook 1 will run everyday at 7AM to update the data.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AG8S0.png)

I have looked online but seem to not find a solution, as most solution points to using Jupyterlab in Vertex AI. Does anyone know how to automate this process? Should I use Google Cloud Functions for this?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78169458/schedule-a-run-for-vertex-ai-colab-notebook-and-workbench-notebook