# Schedule a run for Vertex AI Colab notebook and Workbench Notebook

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-workflows, google-cloud-colab-enterprise

I want to call VertexAI colab notebook and workbench notebook in google workflows. Please let me know in case if there is any direct way to call or through cloud functions.

I have checked the google documentations and I was not able to find any method to call the colab notebooks directly or through APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Today you can execute Notebooks using Notebook Executor.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/schedule-and-execute-notebooks-with-vertex-ai-workbench

Colab Notebooks (.ipynb) files are compatible.

Notebook Executor provides an API. Example: https://gist.github.com/gogasca/eaf4cc1ee0c0f45ab0ebebb1bf0ef253